# 'TcpListener' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Net.Sockets'

Tags: vb.net, tcplistener

I got 11 errors in my VB program. All the errors look similar: *X is ambiguous in the namespace Y*

```
Error line: Imports System.Net.Sockets  
            Imports System.Text  
            Module Module1  
            Sub Main()
```

```
Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), 8888)
```

How might I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you've added two different references for assemblies that define `System.Net.Sockets`. (Probably `System.dll` for .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0, but that's neither here nor there.)

I say this because [there's nothing wrong with your code](http://ideone.com/rDSQH):

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

Sub Main()
  Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), 8888)
End Sub

End Module
```

`result: success         time: 0.16s    memory: 25064 kB     returned value: 0`

Comment: Just now i dete the reference "System" and the above error gone. But now there is another error now. {"The requested address is not valid in its context"}